# Geometry not showing when importing Dutch BRT-files (GML)

Tags: qgis, geometry, gml

After importing a couple of gml files (Dutch BRT-files) into QGIS I noticed that some of the layers didn't seem to contain any geometry, the database (attribute table) is there, but no geometry is showing on my screen.

When I import the gml separately, it shows up just fine.It looks like the gml files are interfering with each other?

Any thoughts?

[image: single GML imported separately, roads are showing]

[image: multiple GML files imported at once, roads are gone]

Comment: looks like gml not xml see https://www.pdok.nl/en/products/pdok-downloads/downloadservice-basis-registratie-topografie-brt

Comment: You are right, my mistake, I will edit the original post.

Comment: which version of qgis? possible bug with the mac version? gdal drivers http://www.gdal.org/drv_gml.html

Answer (score 1):

It isn't neccessary that your XML file contains a single layer, nor that that layer has any kind of geometry data. First, QGis will load all layers it can interpret from the XML file, and in case where it can't find geometry data for a specific feature class (layer), it will add it as a table not a QgsLayer. You can still open its attribute value, but since there is no geometry, you can't visualize it.

Check if your data perhaps contains columns like x/y, which you can use to produce geometry, or maybe a serialized geometry column (WKT format)

Answer (score 0):

The source data is in GML format not XML

This is a sample of the data in QGIS 3.01

[image]

So load in the gml in QGIS and you should see it render point lines and polygons, then change the colour, line and fill to you prefered standard.

Comment: The files are indeed gml-files, but still, sometimes it shows geometry and the other time it doesn't.

Comment: My answer still applies, GML is just an XML document using the predefined GML schema rules.

Comment: The gml doesn't show any items when I load a bunch of gml at once. It does show geometry when I load the gml separately.